# How to assert two dynamic values in postman?

Tags: postman

I"m having a postman test to check for two values in the response. Here' the code snippet below

```
pm.test('Validate the Response', function () {       
    var json = pm.response.json();

    id1 = pm.globals.get("global_var1");
    id2 = pm.globals.get("global_var2");

    pm.expect(json.ids).to.eql([id1,id2]);
});
```

Here the id1 and id2 values randomly change ( i.e test101,test102 or test202,test203 or test403,test401)
Since they don't follow an order, how i make the assertion to check the  values in any order during assertion?

Comment: What does your response body look like? Is `ids` a string, object, array?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the structure of your response data but if it's like this:

```
{ 
    "ids":  "test101,test102"
}
```

Then a check like this can be what you need:

```
pm.test('Validate the Response', () => {       

    let idList = _.get(pm.response.json(), "ids"),
        id1 = pm.globals.get("global_var1"),
        id2 = pm.globals.get("global_var2");

    pm.expect(idList).to.include(id1,id2);
});
```

Comment: Sorry to get back on this after long time, The Id's return is an array. i will try this solution